# terraform data source external with bash script throwing error with JSON structure

Tags: terraform, jq

I am getting error when executing my (bash) shell script via terraform data source external.
Here is my terraform code

```
resource "random_id" "win_serv" {
  byte_length = 4
}

locals {
  username = "kerbuser1"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "win_serv_instance" {
  project      = "burnished-fold-328804"
  name         = "krb-test-${random_id.win_serv.hex}"
  machine_type = "e2-standard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-b"

  metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-ps1 = <<EOT
# Installing IIS
Import-Module servermanager
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature

# Ensure the directory exists
if (-not (Test-Path("C:\inetpub\wwwroot"))) {New-Item "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" -Type Directory}

# Write the expanded string out to the file, overwriting the file if it already exists.
"<html><body><p>Windows startup script added directly.</p></body></html>" | Out-File -FilePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html -Encoding ascii -Force
EOT
  }

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "windows-server-2004-dc-core-v20211115"
      size  = "50"
      type = "pd-ssd"
    }
  }

  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }

  service_account {
    email  = "292284418153-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
}

data "external" "kerb_auth" {
  program = [ "bash", "${path.module}/kerb_auth.sh" ]
  query = {
    ZONE     = "us-central1-b"
    ID       = "burnished-fold-328804"
    HOSTNAME = "${google_compute_instance.win_serv_instance.name}"
  }
}
```

and here is my bash shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME="kerbuser1"
USER_EMAIL="kerbuser1@f5lbu.com"
EXPIRE_DATE=$(date --date='now +10 minutes' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
WORKING_DIR="/tmp/krbloc"

#Variables provided in external block query format of the instance tf template
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "HOSTNAME=\(.HOSTNAME) ZONE=\(.ZONE) ID=\(.ID)"')"

# generate rsa public and private keys
mkdir -p ${WORKING_DIR}
cd ${WORKING_DIR}
openssl genrsa -out private_key 2048 > /dev/null 2>&1
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key -out public_key > /dev/null 2>&1
openssl rsa -in public_key -pubin -text -noout

MODULUS=$(cat public_key | grep -v -- ----- | base64 -d | dd bs=1 skip=33 count=256 2>/dev/null | base64 -w 0; echo)
EXPONENT=$(cat public_key | grep -v -- ----- | base64 -d | dd bs=1 skip=291 count=3 2>/dev/null | base64)

printf '{"userName": "%s", "modulus": "%s", "exponent": "%s", "expireOn": "%s", "email": "%s"}' "${USERNAME}" "${MODULUS}" "${EXPONENT}" "${EXPIRE_DATE}" "${USER_EMAIL}" > metadata_payload.json

if [[ -f metadata_payload.json ]]; then
  gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${HOSTNAME} --project ${ID} --zone ${ZONE} --metadata-from-file="windows-keys=metadata_payload.json"

else
  echo "Payload file not found."
fi

KRB=$(gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output ${HOSTNAME} --project=${ID} --zone=${ZONE} --port=4 | jq -r -c --arg MODULUS $MODULUS 'select(.modulus == $MODULUS) | .encryptedPassword')

PAS=$(echo $KRB | base64 -d | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private_key -oaep)

jq -n --arg passwd "$PAS" '{"password":$passwd}'
```

when executing the script manually, I don't see any issues.
but getting below error while executing from terraform
I suspect its because the password which I am returning in shell script have special character's.
I have tried altering the quotes and escape characters, but no luck.

```
data.external.kerb_auth: Reading...
╷
│ Error: command "bash" produced invalid JSON: invalid character 'R' looking for beginning of value
│
│   with data.external.kerb_auth,
│   on main.tf line 76, in data "external" "kerb_auth":
│   76: data "external" "kerb_auth" {
│
╵
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to isolate the problem? Try to create a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The jq looks okay, it seems more likely your script outputs extra stuff before it runs jq. But I can't debug all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the detailed question... but thanks for the clue... 
I found the issue, if you run a shell script from terraform via data source external then it expects the output of the script should be formatted in Json. 

My scripts returns an output from few gcloud commands

-Issue-1

```
openssl rsa -in public_key -pubin -text -noout
```

it returns an encoded version of private but I am taking any input from this command, so I removed this command from the script.

-Issue-2

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${HOSTNAME} --project ${ID} --zone ${ZONE} --metadata-from-file="windows-keys=metadata_payload.json"
```

It returns an update status, for which I updated as below

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata ${HOSTNAME} --project ${ID} --zone ${ZONE} --metadata-from-file="windows-keys=metadata_payload.json" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

-Issue-3

```
gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output ${HOSTNAME} --project=${ID} --zone=${ZONE} --port=4
```

It returns an exception, for which I updated as below

```
gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output ${HOSTNAME} --project=${ID} --zone=${ZONE} --port=4 2>/dev/null
```